# I love fishing, dancing, playing, crafting, and fighting

Tags: riddle

I'm not a sketch, but I can be drawn,
I'm not origami, but I can be folded,
I'm not a pill, but I can be swallowed,
I'm not a haircut, but I can be short or long,
I love fishing, dancing, playing, crafting, and fighting,

What am I?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are a:

> Sword. Swords are drawn, metal is folded into a sword, sword-swallowing, short sword and long sword. Also, swordfish, sword dance, swordplay, craft a sword or SwordCraft, swordfight.